# Line breaks in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to leave multiple empty lines.

I tried

```
PRINT 09h,09h
```

and

```
CALL PTHIS
DB 13, 10, '', 0 
CALL PTHIS
DB 13, 10, '', 0
```

The first method seems to leave a single line regardless the number of 09h I use while the second is obviously not very practical.

How can I make multiple line breaks in assembly?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of assembler you're using, but `db 13,10,13,10,0` should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`09H` is a `TAB` character, not a `LINE FEED` character. If you get a single line, then your `PRINT` macro would appear to add a newline.

Try using

```
PRINT 10,10,10,10
```

Can't guarantee it, though - I've no idea what assembler you're using.

Answer (score 0):

"I tried PRINT 09h,09h"

PRINT 0Ah,0Ah if you want it in hex

0Ah is a line feed

0Dh is a carriage return

So if you want to leave the cursor in the middle of the page when you drop down a line exclude the 0Dh bit